# Linq Query Null check returning bool error

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
  var qry = from sv in Context.DocStore_SearchValues
            where sv.Category == category
            select sv;
  return qry.FirstOrDefault() != null;
```

I am getting this message:

> Unable to create a constant value of
>   type
>   'SSS.Model.Suburban.DocStore_Category'.
>   Only primitive types ('such as Int32,
>   String, and Guid') are supported in
>   this context.

How do I check for null? I tried as a string and I got the same message:

return string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry.FirstOrDefault().ToString());

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Eroc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a non-primitive type in the `where` clause.

Change it to something like

```
where sv.Category.Name == someString
```

Comment: Thank you! I went with:
  var qry = from sv in Context.DocStore_SearchValues
            where sv.Category.Name == category.Name
            select sv;

Answer (score 0):

How about using the IEquatable Interface implemented for the Category class to make the point of encapsulating what you are trying to do in the query with an non-primitive type inside the object itself? 
So it looks something like this:

```
 var qry = from sv in Context.DocStore_SearchValues 
        where sv.Category.Equals(yourCategory) == true
        select sv; 


 return qry.Any();
```

Then you would use a partial file class to extend the Category class to implement the comparison logic.

Answer (score 0):

you'd generally want to do something like where category.Id == id  instead of comparing strings, imo